# Getting Energies and Probabilities from the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

So I need to find the possible energies and the probabilities of these using the eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian.

Once I obtain the eigenvalues, are those the energies E_n in and of themselves?
Or do they simply give me the n values, i.e. n = 1, 2, 3, that I would then plug in to the equation

[image: Equation for finding energies]

Or is it both? Do they both yield the same answer? (I am still waiting on the installation of the computer program to use to find the eigenvalues)

Finally, I am completely at a loss as to how to go on to find the probabilities of the energies. I am not given a traditional wavefunction to normalize, so how do I find the probability without the normalization constant?

EDIT: I normally don't like to put problem specifics from my homework on here, but I suppose it's hard to understand what I mean by "I am not given a traditional wave function." As such, the exact problem is stated:

> Models describing electrons on a crystal lattice are very important to
>   understanding various phenomena in solids. Here we consider a model in
>   which an electron lives on a one-dimensional lattice of N sites. The
>   sites are labeled by i=1,2, ....,N. The system looks like
>
> ```
>   o----o----o-- .... --o----o
>   1       2       3           N-1       N
> ```
>
> The state of the electron is then a vector of dimension N. The
>   Hamiltonian is given by an N by N matrix whose elements are:
>
> ```
>                 / - 1,  if i and j are near-neighbors; 
>    H_{ij} = |
>                  \ 0  ,  otherwise.
> ```
>
> Physically, the electron can be thought of as hopping from site to
>   site through a near-neighbor hopping. As you see, the Hamiltonian
>   resembles the one we obtained in class when we discretized the problem
>   of a particle in a box.  Suppose we prepare the electron in a state
>   |a> with equal amplitude for all N sites, i.e., a(1)=a(2)=....=a(N).
>   To be specific, let's consider N=5.
>
> ```
> What is the lowest value we can find if we measure the energy of the electron? With what probability?
> List all the possible (i.e., with non-zero probability) energy values that we could find in such a measurement.
> ```

So I used Maple to obtain eigenvalues for N=5, and thus have the energies.

So I suppose the root of my question is: if I am only given this information, how do I know what state the electron is in? Is it as simple as the corresponding eigenvector for each eigenvalue? Can I assume anything about the wave function (i.e. follows particle in a box method)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just "plug into the equation" is always a bad idea. So here is a short overview:

- Given a Hamiltonian, the possible energy levels correspond to the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian (no "plugging in" needed). More precisely, we have $H|\psi\rangle=E|\psi\rangle$ for every eigenvector.
- Given a normalized eigenvector, you can find the probability by $\langle \psi |H|\psi \rangle$, otherwise you have to normalize (divide by $\langle \psi|\psi \rangle$).
- In the density matrix formalism, this means that given a state $\rho$ (positive semidefinite matrix with trace one - otherwise normalize the trace) the probability is given by $\operatorname{tr}(\rho H)$ gives you the probability.

So the question is: what do you mean "I am not given a traditional wavefunction to normalize"?

EDIT: To me, it seems that you are given a perfectly reasonable wave function (in matrix formulation, though). An electron that sits just at site $j$ will have corresponding wave function $|e_j\rangle$, where $e_j$ denotes the $j$-th basis vector (i.e. $|e_j\rangle=(0,\ldots, 0,1,0,\ldots 0)^T$ with the $1$ at position j. Following your assignment, this tells you the wave function of your particle looks like:
$$ |a\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^N a|e_i\rangle$$
where $a$ is a complex number and $N|a|^2=1$ for normalization.

In order to find the probabilities, you can now either compute the eigenvectors of $H$ and then decompose $|a\rangle$ in terms of these eigenvectors, or you can compute the spectral decomposition of $H$, i.e. the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and projectors $P_i$ such that $H=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i P_i$ and compute $\langle a|P_i|a\rangle$ to obtain the probability of measuring $\lambda_i$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Hamiltonian, first you find the eigenvalues (which are the $E_n$s as Martin pointed out). Then you find the eigenvectors or eigenfunctions associated with each eigenvalue by plugging each eigenvalue in "$H|\psi_n> =E_n|\psi_n>$" and solving the equation.
Then, if I'm right and you have been given a specific state, say $|\Psi>$, you have to write this state in terms of the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian. Doing so, the coefficients of each eigenvector in $|\Psi>$ is the square root of the respective probability you're looking for.
 If not so, I agree with Martin on :

> ... the question is: what do you mean "I am not given a traditional wavefunction to normalize"?